# Are James 2:26 and Leviticus 17:11 contradictory?

Tags: leviticus, james

The spirit is the animating force of the body. As well, the blood accomplishes the same. When contrasted, the following passages appear to be
contradict one another:

- **Leviticus 17:11**: "‘For the life of the flesh is *in the blood*'... <sup>14</sup>For as for the life of all flesh, its blood is identified with its life" (cf. Gen. 9:4, etc.).

We then have the following declaration from the Letter of James:

- **James 2:26**: "For just as the body without the spirit is dead..."

That is: "The body *with the spirit* is alive." How can these verses be reconciled?

Comment: No doubt these passages can be drawn together, but that's systematic theology and off-topic on this site.

Comment: Do you mean this as a contradiction question? If so the contradiction you're seeing should be more clearly explained.

Comment: Hmm. They just don't seem contradictory to me. We need many things to be alive. And James is just using it as a metaphor, he's probably quoting a common aphorism.

Comment: Yes, body dualism is the common position of Christians. Which, I would've thought, would solve this issue without any apparent contradiction. There's no human life without body and soul/spirit.

Comment: Life without breath is dead. If you stop breathing you die.  If you bleed to death you die.